# "Data was enetred into computer" "I entered the room"

Tags: past-tense, past-simple

For "Data" I reckon it is correct to say "Data was enterned into computer correctly".

And i reckon for myself "I entered the room" is correct and is " i was entered the room" is correct or wrong?

"Make sure that the data was entenered correctly" is also grammatically Could i know if my interpretations are right?

Comment: Do you have access to a spellchecker?  This question would benefit from a spell check to catch the typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

correct: I **entered** the room. Incorrect: I entered *into* the room.

*but* correct: I **went into** the room. correct: They **entered into** an agreement.

Passive Voice -

correct: Data was **entered into** the computer. The names are **entered into** a database. The new data has been **entered into** the computer.

incorrect: I was entered the room.

Answer (score 0):

All are correct.

It would be odd, but not incorrect to say "I was entered into the room", but it would not be odd to say "I was entered into the race (by my club)"

It would be a little odd to say "Data enters the computer", but it's possible.  Imagine an automatic weather system: "The gauges record temperature and pressure.  This data enters the computer through the wireless connection and a daily graph is automatically uploaded to Twitter"

But usually somebody needs to type the data in so "Data was entered (by somebody) makes sense.  And usually you can walk into a room by yourself, so "I entered the room".

"I was entered the room" is incorrect.  Passive verbs don't take direct objects.

Comment: As you said it is little odd to say "I was enetered into room" but how about "I was enertered a room"?

Comment: Then do you not think that "I was entered into room" should also be wrong just like "I was entered the room"?

Comment: It is correct grammar. It just doesn't have a reasonable and sensible meaning.  However "I was entered into a race" (which has the same structure) is completely correct.

Comment: Also, please check your spelling of "entered":  You have "enetered"  "enertered" "enetred" and "entenered".

Comment: KThanks and how about data entered into the computer" is it also grmmatically correct?

Comment: Grammatically correct. But it's unlikely to be meaningful  Like saying "A pig's feathers are thoughtful".

Comment: I believe "Data entered/has entered into computer" is grammatically correct but "Data has been entered into computer" is probably more correct. Am i right?

Comment: They have different meanings, they are both correct.  The first is unlikely to be what you want to say.  Please see the answer and the examples.  Don't confuse grammar with meaningfulness.  You probably don't mean "data entered the computer".  But grammatically it is correct.  You probably mean "Somebody entered data into the computer" or "Data was entered into the computer."

Answer (score 0):

"I was entered into the room" is correct but "I entered the room" is better to use. Data was entered into computer is correct but it is better to use "the" before "computer".

Comment: I reckon "I was entered into the room=someone entered me into the room. I was entered the room is wrong.Am I right?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  Which asks about "I was entered the room", not "...into the room"